# MYSQL join and group by five field per store

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to get a complex (at least to me) MySQL query, and I can't get the result that I want.

I have one DB with 2 tables:

**stores**

> id, name

**products**

> id, store_id, hardware, name, price, url, notify

I want to get 3 products per store_id with notify = 1, hardware = 'gpu' and order by price asc.

So if I launch this SQL sentence:

```sql
SELECT s.name as store, p.id as id, p.name as name, p.hardware as hw, p.price as price, p.url as url, p.notify as notify
FROM products p JOIN stores s
ON p.store_id = s.id
AND p.hardware='gpu'
AND p.notify = 1
GROUP BY store
ORDER BY p.price asc;
```

I only get one product per store_id, and I'd like to get (maximum) tree elements per store_id. Something like next example:

| store | id | name | hw | price | url | notify |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | 1 | name1 | gpu | price | url | 1 |
| store1 | 2 | name2 | gpu | price | url | 1 |
| store1 | 3 | name3 | gpu | price | url | 1 |
| store2 | 8 | name8 | gpu | price | url | 1 |
| store2 | 12 | name12 | gpu | price | url | 1 |
| store3 | 22 | name22 | gpu | price | url | 1 |

And so on...

How can I do that?

### Example data

**stores**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `afiliate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**products**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hardware` char(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `notify` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Store_id_to_products` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Store_id_to_products` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `stores` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1961 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```sql
select id, name from stores;
```

**result**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Amazon |
| 2 | Ebay |
| 3 | BestBuy |
| 4 | Target |

```sql
select * from products;
```

**result**

| id | store_id | hardware | name | price | notify |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | gpu | EVGA GeForce RTX 3070 FTW3 Ultra Gaming 8GB GDDR6 | 949.00 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | gpu | Zotac Gaming GeForce RTX 3090 Trinity OC 24GB GDDR6X | 2259.00 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | gpu | EVGA GeForce RTX 3090 FTW3 Ultra Gaming 24GB GDDR6X | 2749.00 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | gpu | Asus TUF Gaming GeForce RTX 3090 OC Edition 24GB GDDR6X | 2549.00 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | gpu | Gigabyte GTX 1660 Super OC 6G | 489.00 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | gpu | Asus TUF GTX 1660 Super OC 6GB | 428.99 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | gpu | GIGABYTE RTX 3060 GAMING OC 12GB | 689.00 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | gpu | Gigabyte RTX 3080 Aorus Master 10GB | 1398.99 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | gpu | Asus ROG Strix RTX 3080 OC 10GB Blanca | 1312.00 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | gpu | Gigabyte RTX 3080 Gaming OC 10GB | 1258.99 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | gpu | Asus ROG Strix RTX 3090 OC Gaming 24GB | 2599.00 | 1 |
| 13 | 4 | gpu | Asus TUF Gaming Radeon RX 6800 OC 16GB | 1078.99 | 1 |
| 14 | 4 | gpu | GIGABYTE RX6800XT GAMING OC 16GB | 450.00 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 | gpu | Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1660 Ti OC 6G | 499.95 | 1 |
| 16 | 4 | gpu | ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER Twin Fan | 529.95 | 1 |

I'm trying to do a SQL sentence that get 3 cheapest products per store. This is the result that I want:

| id | store_id | hardware | name | price | notify |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | gpu | EVGA GeForce RTX 3070 FTW3 Ultra Gaming 8GB GDDR6 | 949.00 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | gpu | Zotac Gaming GeForce RTX 3090 Trinity OC 24GB GDDR6X | 2259.00 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | gpu | Asus TUF Gaming GeForce RTX 3090 OC Edition 24GB GDDR6X | 2549.00 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | gpu | Gigabyte GTX 1660 Super OC 6G | 489.00 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | gpu | Asus TUF GTX 1660 Super OC 6GB | 428.99 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | gpu | GIGABYTE RTX 3060 GAMING OC 12GB | 689.00 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | gpu | Asus ROG Strix RTX 3080 OC 10GB Blanca | 1312.00 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | gpu | Gigabyte RTX 3080 Gaming OC 10GB | 1258.99 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | gpu | Asus ROG Strix RTX 3090 OC Gaming 24GB | 2599.00 | 1 |
| 14 | 4 | gpu | GIGABYTE RX6800XT GAMING OC 16GB | 450.00 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 | gpu | Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1660 Ti OC 6G | 499.95 | 1 |
| 16 | 4 | gpu | ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER Twin Fan | 529.95 | 1 |

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you add the example datas that provide your expected result and  tables `products`, `stores` description as well ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? (The "cheapest three per store" is *much* easier in MySQL8, but it looks as though you're using 5.x?)

Comment: @MatBailie mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your MySQL version is lower than 8+ you could use :

```
SELECT
      t1.id,
      name,
      hardware,
      price,
      notify
FROM (
        SELECT
              id,
              store_id,
              hardware,
              notify,
              price,
              @rn := IF(@prev = store_id, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
              @prev := store_id
        FROM products
        JOIN ( SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
        where hardware='gpu' and notify=1
        ORDER BY  price ASC
    ) AS t1
INNER JOIN   stores st on  t1.store_id=st.id
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY   id asc ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50e598d63d710e6c9f7a347cb3f157c4)

In MySQL 8+

```
WITH my_table  AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY  price ASC ) AS rownum
  FROM products
)
SELECT my_table.id,st.name,hardware,my_table.name,price,notify
FROM my_table 
INNER JOIN  stores st on  my_table.store_id=st.id
WHERE  rownum <= 5
order by my_table.id asc;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48ac82cd8da908f7976c65d430a45ffd)

Comment: I love you sooooo much !! hehe thanks a lot

Comment: are there any way to return store name instead of store_id ?

Comment: @jask updated both queries

Comment: You are the best !!!